# Flutter TextFormField tipo hora en web

Tags: flutter, dart, webforms

Hola estoy haciendo un form en flutter que en uno de los inputs del usuario es para hora, pero la aplicación será solo para web y no me deja escribir el input nada del teclado ¿alguien sabe como podría solucionarlo?

```
TextFormField(
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(
      RegExp(r'^([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$'),
    ),
  ],
  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
  autocorrect: false,
  decoration: _inputDecoration('7:45 am'),
  keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime,
  onSaved: (value) {
    time = value;
  },
  validator: (value) {
    if (value!.isEmpty) {
      return 'Este campo es obligatorio';
    }
    return null;
  },
),
```

Comment: hola, tienes actualizado flutter?

Comment: Sí, tengo la última versión de flutter

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando una app web en Flutter y usas

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.datetime
```

, esto es incorrecto ya que no es soportado en web.

Debes usar:

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.text
```